# a complicated Sum

Tags: summation

I don't know how i can calculate this complicated multivariate sum : 
$$
S(l,k)=\sum_{|m|=k} s_{l,m}=\sum_{|m|=k} l(l-1)(l-2)\dots(l-m+1)
$$ 
Where $m=(m_1,\dots,m_n)$, $l=(l_1,\dots,l_n)$, and $k$ a non-negative integer and $|m|=m_1+\dots+m_n$.
when a term of  this sum is explicitly for a $m=(m_1,\dots,m_n)$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n |m_i|=k$ :
$$
s_{l,m}=\prod_{j=1}^{n}l_j \times\prod_{j=1}^{n}(l_j-1)\times\dots\times \prod_{j=1}^{n}(l_j-m_j+1)
$$

Comment: Hi! Is this a question about `Mathematica` or math in general?

Comment: Hi @Hamza, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basic rules of the site. Your question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) because it seems to be [off-topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), ie its about mathematics and not Mathematica. If that's not the case, please [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to make it explicitly about Mathematica programming. Include a minimum example of the code you are working on.

Comment: Hi, my problem is how i can calculate a such sum with Mathematica, i mean that how i can calculate a multivariate sum with such condition ?